# Como hacer data-target de un boton hacia una clase existente

Tags: html, clase, modal

Como vinculo la clase del modal aplicado en el H2 sobre la imagen que se encuentra adentro de button? Necesito que al hacer click sobre la imagen despliegue el modal al igual que lo hace el H2

Se puede ver el código completo con css e imagenes en este link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nb7Ktdg_tFF59Ee2so9YvSE_VGwo7n3W

Gracias desde ya.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: Raleway;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 1845px;
  margin-top:0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------*/
#AbreModal{ 
   display: block; 

   height: auto; 
   text-align: center; 
   line-height: 27px; 
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
   color: white; 
   font-size:0.8em; 
   font-weight: bolder;cursor: pointer;
   text-align:center
}
#AbreModal:hover{
 color:gold;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
.VentModal{ 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
   position: fixed; 
   top: -100%; 
   left: 0px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
transition: all 1s; 
} 
#ActivaVentana{ 
   display: none; 
} 
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .VentModal{ 
   top: 0%; 
} 

#CierraModal{ 
 display:none;
   width: 40px; 
   height: 40px; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: -20px; 
   right: -20px; 
   color: white; 
   font-size: 1.3em; 
   background-color: #black; 
   line-height: 40px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 50%; 
} 
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .contenidoventana{ 
   top: 10%; 
}
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .contenidoventana2{ 
   top: 10%; 
}
.contenidoventana{ 
   width: 48%; 
   height: auto; 
   background-color: rgba(241,196,15,.9); 
   
   
   padding: 20px; 
   pointer-events: auto; 
   position: fixed; 
   left: 480px; 
   top: -800px; 
 
   transition: all 1s; 
   text-align: justify; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
} 
.contenidoventana p{
 color:#212F3C;
}
.contenidoventana2{ 
   width: 48%; 
   height: auto; 
   background-color: rgba(241,196,15,.9); 
   
   
   padding: 20px; 
   pointer-events: auto; 
   position: fixed; 
   left: 480px; 
   top: -800px; 
 
   transition: all 1s; 
   text-align: justify; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
} 
.contenidoventana2 p{
 color:#212F3C;
}
.texto-ventana{
 font-size: 0.9em; 
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 float:left;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:30px;
 margin:auto;
 
}
.imagen-ventana1{
 top:-700px;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
.imagen-ventana1 img{
 padding-top:30px;
 width:200%;
 height:auto;
 margin:auto;
 padding-left:30%;
 height:60%;
 }

.imagen-ventana1 h3{
 font-family:Sigmar;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:75%;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 color:#212F3C;
 font-size:1.4em;
}
.imagen-ventana2{
 top:-700px;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
.imagen-ventana2 img{
 padding-top:30px;
 width:200%;
 height:auto;
 margin:auto;
 padding-left:30%;
 height:60%;
 }

.imagen-ventana2 h3{
 font-family:Sigmar;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:75%;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 color:#212F3C;
 font-size:1.4em;
}
button {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 border:0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------*/

h1 {padding-top:19px;
   color: gold;
   font-size:40px;
   font-family: Sigmar;
}
  
p {
  color: white;
}
.contenedor {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 margin:0px auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);*/

} 
.videos{
 float:right;
 max-width:60%;
 margin-right:20px;
 padding-top:30px;
}
.texto-contenido{
 
 margin:0px auto;
 color: white;
 font-family: Raleway;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align: justify;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.texto-interno{
 float:left;
 width:38%; 
}
.boton {
 width:auto;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 20px;
 color: gold;
 font-size:20px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:link{
 color:gold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:visited{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:hover{
 color:gold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.tapita-1{
 float:left;
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.tapita{
 padding-top:20px;
 float:left;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.tapas-todas{
 margin-top:40px;
}
.tapita-4{
 float:left;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.sello{
 padding-top:0px;
 float:left;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.sello img {
-webkit-transition:all .9s ease; /* Safari y Chrome */
-moz-transition:all .9s ease; /* Firefox */
-o-transition:all .9s ease; /* IE 9 */
-ms-transition:all .9s ease; /* Opera */
width:100%;
}
.sello:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.03);
-moz-transform:scale(1.03);
-ms-transform:scale(1.03);
-o-transform:scale(1.03);
transform:scale(1.03);
}
.sello {/*Ancho y altura son modificables al requerimiento de cada uno*/
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tapita-1">

<button data-target="#AbreModal"><img src="imagenes/maquina.png" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1"></button>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="ActivaVentana" id="ActivaVentana"> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" id="AbreModal"><h2>La máquina del tiempo</h2></label> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" class="VentModal"> </label> 
<div class="contenidoventana"> 
   <label for="ActivaVentana" id="CierraModal">X</label> 
<div class="texto-ventana">
<p>Este material tiene por objetivo colaborar en la labor diaria de los docentes, maestros y profesores. Las propuestas de trabajo que se incluyen pueden ser moldeadas de acuerdo a sus expectativas, su experiencia y a las características del grupo con el que trabajen. Se organiza de la siguiente manera: 
<br><br><br>
1. Una breve reseña histórico-teórica sobre el género de la novela gráfica, seguida de una serie de actividades sugeridas para comenzar a abordar las particularidades del imbricado vínculo entre texto e imagen. 
<br><br>
2. Actividades pensadas para trabajar el texto en sí mismo y la comprensión lectora que requiere ciertas habilidades indispensables para interpretar un relato. 
<br><br>
3. Propuestas de reescritura: habilidad para reconocer y dominar otros géneros discursivos, de modo tal que sean capaces de dominar los respectivos registros y léxicos de cada uno. 
<br><br>
4. Actividades interdisciplinarias que articulan el trabajo con otras materias, vinculando a alumnos y docentes en un proyecto creativo e innovador. Pueden servir de disparador para compartir espacios extracurriculares que permitan conceptualizar la lectura como actividad de (re)creación y exploración de nuevas miradas y modos de representar el mundo. 
<br><br>
Esperamos que este material sea de su agrado y que acompañe de manera fructífera su valiosa e inconmensurable labor educativa diaria.
</p></div>
                <div class="imagen-ventana1">
<h3>La máquina del tiempo</h3>

                 <img src="imagenes/cuadernillos/maquinacuadernillo.jpg"> </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer podrías tratar de  explicarte mejor ?

Comment: Que tal @CamiloVasquez, lo que intento hacer es que al hacer click sobre la imagen que se encuentra dentro de Button, despliegue el modal creado con clases aplicado sobre el H2 que se ve en el código, me dijeron que tengo que llamarlo con data-target y que ponga la imagen adentro de button, ahora interactua como boton, pero no despliega el modal, yo supongo que lo estoy llamando mal, pero no logro corregirlo

Comment: El modal es de bootstrap ? pregunto por que bootstrap usa data-target para llamar un modal pero tu modal no tiene estructura de modal de bootstrap

Comment: Nose, me recomendaron esa etiqueta, pero puede ser otra, mientras cumpla la función, de bootstrap no se nada

Comment: Siendo así te hace falta el javascript para eso, tienes javascript hecho ?

Comment: No @CamiloVasquez, intente realizarlo solo con html y css, me funcionaba con los titulos puestos en el H2, pero al intentar aplicarlo en la imagen me encontre con que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Agrega tu código css ...

Answer (score 3):

Viendo tu código completo la solución que deberías aplicar es meter la imagen dentro de un `<label for="ActivaVentana" id="AbreModal"></label>` y no dentro de un botón.

Tu código funciona de la siguiente manera:

El `label#AbreModal` apunta a un elemento de tipo `checkbox`, cuando este elemento está checkeado se ejecuta una regla que indica que el modal va a tener un top de `0px` haciendo que se muestre, entonces para que el modal abra haciendo click en la `img` debes simplemente meterla dentro del `label` que apunta a ese `checkbox`.

**Nota:** como ahora vamos a tener dos etiquetas `label` con el mismo nombre debemos cambiar el atributo `id` por `class` **recuerda que el `id` es un identificador único he irrepetible en el sitio**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: Raleway;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 1845px;
  margin-top:0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

/*------------------------------------------------------*/
.AbreModal{ 
   display: block; 

   height: auto; 
   text-align: center; 
   line-height: 27px; 
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
   color: white; 
   font-size:0.8em; 
   font-weight: bolder;cursor: pointer;
   text-align:center
}
.AbreModal:hover{
 color:gold;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
.VentModal{ 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
   position: fixed; 
   top: -100%; 
   left: 0px; 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
transition: all 1s; 
} 
#ActivaVentana{ 
   display: none; 
} 
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .VentModal{ 
   top: 0%; 
} 

#CierraModal{ 
 display:none;
   width: 40px; 
   height: 40px; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: -20px; 
   right: -20px; 
   color: white; 
   font-size: 1.3em; 
   background-color: #black; 
   line-height: 40px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-radius: 50%; 
} 
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .contenidoventana{ 
   top: 10%; 
}
#ActivaVentana:checked ~ .contenidoventana2{ 
   top: 10%; 
}
.contenidoventana{ 
   width: 48%; 
   height: auto; 
   background-color: rgba(241,196,15,.9); 
   
   
   padding: 20px; 
   pointer-events: auto; 
   position: fixed; 
   left: 480px; 
   top: -800px; 
 
   transition: all 1s; 
   text-align: justify; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
} 
.contenidoventana p{
 color:#212F3C;
}
.contenidoventana2{ 
   width: 48%; 
   height: auto; 
   background-color: rgba(241,196,15,.9); 
   
   
   padding: 20px; 
   pointer-events: auto; 
   position: fixed; 
   left: 480px; 
   top: -800px; 
 
   transition: all 1s; 
   text-align: justify; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
} 
.contenidoventana2 p{
 color:#212F3C;
}
.texto-ventana{
 font-size: 0.9em; 
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 float:left;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:30px;
 margin:auto;
 
}
.imagen-ventana1{
 top:-700px;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
.imagen-ventana1 img{
 padding-top:30px;
 width:200%;
 height:auto;
 margin:auto;
 padding-left:30%;
 height:60%;
 }

.imagen-ventana1 h3{
 font-family:Sigmar;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:75%;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 color:#212F3C;
 font-size:1.4em;
}
.imagen-ventana2{
 top:-700px;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
.imagen-ventana2 img{
 padding-top:30px;
 width:200%;
 height:auto;
 margin:auto;
 padding-left:30%;
 height:60%;
 }

.imagen-ventana2 h3{
 font-family:Sigmar;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:75%;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 color:#212F3C;
 font-size:1.4em;
}
button {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 border:0;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------*/

h1 {padding-top:19px;
   color: gold;
   font-size:40px;
   font-family: Sigmar;
}
  
p {
  color: white;
}
.contenedor {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 margin:0px auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);*/

} 
.videos{
 float:right;
 max-width:60%;
 margin-right:20px;
 padding-top:30px;
}
.texto-contenido{
 
 margin:0px auto;
 color: white;
 font-family: Raleway;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align: justify;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.texto-interno{
 float:left;
 width:38%; 
}
.boton {
 width:auto;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 20px;
 color: gold;
 font-size:20px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:link{
 color:gold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:visited{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.boton a:hover{
 color:gold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.tapita-1{
 float:left;
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.tapita{
 padding-top:20px;
 float:left;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.tapas-todas{
 margin-top:40px;
}
.tapita-4{
 float:left;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.sello{
 padding-top:0px;
 float:left;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
.sello img {
-webkit-transition:all .9s ease; /* Safari y Chrome */
-moz-transition:all .9s ease; /* Firefox */
-o-transition:all .9s ease; /* IE 9 */
-ms-transition:all .9s ease; /* Opera */
width:100%;
}
.sello:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.03);
-moz-transform:scale(1.03);
-ms-transform:scale(1.03);
-o-transform:scale(1.03);
transform:scale(1.03);
}
.sello {/*Ancho y altura son modificables al requerimiento de cada uno*/
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tapita-1">

<label for="ActivaVentana" class="AbreModal"><img src="http://playsol.com/wp-content/uploads/CIRSA-LA-MAQUINA-DEL-TIEMPO-LOGO-300x135.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1"></label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="ActivaVentana" id="ActivaVentana"> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" class="AbreModal"><h2>La máquina del tiempo</h2></label> 
<label for="ActivaVentana" class="VentModal"> </label> 
<div class="contenidoventana"> 
   <label for="ActivaVentana" id="CierraModal">X</label> 
<div class="texto-ventana">
<p>Este material tiene por objetivo colaborar en la labor diaria de los docentes, maestros y profesores. Las propuestas de trabajo que se incluyen pueden ser moldeadas de acuerdo a sus expectativas, su experiencia y a las características del grupo con el que trabajen. Se organiza de la siguiente manera: 
<br><br><br>
1. Una breve reseña histórico-teórica sobre el género de la novela gráfica, seguida de una serie de actividades sugeridas para comenzar a abordar las particularidades del imbricado vínculo entre texto e imagen. 
<br><br>
2. Actividades pensadas para trabajar el texto en sí mismo y la comprensión lectora que requiere ciertas habilidades indispensables para interpretar un relato. 
<br><br>
3. Propuestas de reescritura: habilidad para reconocer y dominar otros géneros discursivos, de modo tal que sean capaces de dominar los respectivos registros y léxicos de cada uno. 
<br><br>
4. Actividades interdisciplinarias que articulan el trabajo con otras materias, vinculando a alumnos y docentes en un proyecto creativo e innovador. Pueden servir de disparador para compartir espacios extracurriculares que permitan conceptualizar la lectura como actividad de (re)creación y exploración de nuevas miradas y modos de representar el mundo. 
<br><br>
Esperamos que este material sea de su agrado y que acompañe de manera fructífera su valiosa e inconmensurable labor educativa diaria.
</p></div>
                <div class="imagen-ventana1">
<h3>La máquina del tiempo</h3>

                 <img src="imagenes/cuadernillos/maquinacuadernillo.jpg"> </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Sos un genio, funciono perfectamente, solo me resta hacer lo mismo con cada tapa, para que cada una despliegue su respectivo titulo e imagen en el modal. De momento todas abren el mismo modal de la primera imagen, como heredando esas propiedades, supongo que por el nombre de las clases o los id, que tendria que cambiar para q cada una muestre lo q coresponde?

Comment: Debes agregar mas checkbox con id unicos por cada modal, agregar los label necesarios que apunten a cada checkbox y en el css aplicar el estilo necesario para cada uno #ActivaVentana:checked ~ .VentModal{ 
   top: 0%; 
}

Comment: @NicolasDure si la respuesta fue tu solución te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a futuros desarrolladores, saludos !

Comment: Justamente estaba intentando aplicarlo a todas las tapas, ni bien termine te puntúo la respuesta y la cierro

Comment: @NicolasDure no es necesario que la cierres, la idea es que la pregunta quede con una respuesta aceptada para que sea de ayuda a próximos desarrolladores que tengan un problema similar :D